# Use sed to replace pattern and insert variable on the inserted string

Tags: bash, variables, sed, replace

In my script, I have the following variable already defined: `GRUB_HG=53737`

I am trying to replace the contents of this file:

```
cat grub.text

{...}
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="random_text_here"
```

I am using `sed` to replace anything that starts with **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=*.**

When I used the following `sed` script, I am replacing the "random_text_here" with a long string. This string contains the variable **$GRUB_HG**, however, when I run the script I am able to replace the "random_text_here" successfully, but the **$GRUB_HG** is not getting replaced with **53737** which was previously defined.

```
Script:
sed -i 's|\GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=.*|GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="hugepages=${GRUB_HG} processor.max_cstates=1 idle=poll pcie_aspm=off intel_iommu=on"|' grub.text
```

This is what the file **grub.text** looks like after the `sed` command:

```
#[ACTUAL OUTPUT]
cat grub.text
{...}
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="hugepages=${GRUB_HG} processor.max_cstates=1 idle=poll pcie_aspm=off intel_iommu=on"
```

I am trying to get something like this:

```
#[DESIRE OUTPUT]
cat grub.text
{...}
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="hugepages=53737 processor.max_cstates=1 idle=poll pcie_aspm=off intel_iommu=on"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double quotes in order for the bash variable to be interpolated in the `sed` command. As you have double quotes in your replacement string you need to escape those:

```
cat grub.text
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="random_text_here"
GRUB_HG=53737 sed -i "s|\GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=.*|GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\"hugepages=${GRUB_HG} processor.max_cstates=1 idle=poll pcie_aspm=off intel_iommu=on\"|" grub.text
cat grub.text
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="hugepages=53737 processor.max_cstates=1 idle=poll pcie_aspm=off intel_iommu=on"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, if you're interested...

Put each of your parameters for GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX into a file, with one on each line.  Whenever you get a new one, just add it to either the top or bottom line, as you choose.

```
hugepages=53737
processor.max_cstates=1
idle=poll
pcie_aspm=off
intel_iommu=on
```

Then when you're ready to add all of them to the variable...

```
cat parameter_file | tr '\n' ' ' > p2
cat << EOF > ed1
1
s/^/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="/
s/$/"/
1W grub.text
wq
EOF

ed -s p2 < ed1
rm -v ./ed1
```

That will put your variable at the end of the file, but from there, you can use either Ed or vim to move it to whichever line you need.